# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: androidx/core/view/ViewCompat when using FlexboxLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-flexboxlayout

I'm using [**`FlexboxLayout`**](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout)

Added below  dependency in `build.gradle` of `FlexboxLayout`

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:1.1.0'
}
```

> myLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



</com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
```

I'm getting below error [Error ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYHm6.png)

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: androidx/core/view/ViewCompat
    at com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout.onLayout_Original(FlexboxLayout.java:565)
    at com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout.onLayout(FlexboxLayout.java)
    at android.view.View.layout_Original(View.java:20672)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.layout(View_Delegate.java:91)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20658)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout_Original(View.java:20672)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.layout(View_Delegate.java:91)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20658)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout_Original(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:444)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java)
    at android.view.View.layout_Original(View.java:20672)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.layout(View_Delegate.java:91)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20658)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1083)
    at android.view.View.layout_Original(View.java:20672)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.layout(View_Delegate.java:91)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20658)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:348)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:386)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:193)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:450)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$3(RenderTask.java:590)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

How can i solve this issue

Thanks in advance. Your efforts will be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solution is here

`FlexboxLayout 1.1.0`, the library is expected to use with [**AndroidX**.](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

If you want to use **`1.1.0 and above`**  than migrate to `AndroidX`

For `AndroidX` use this

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:1.1.0'
}
```

For `com.android.support:appcompat`

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:1.0.0'
}
```

For more information please check [**`FlexboxLayout`**](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout/blob/master/README.md)
Hope this help others